# О «смиренномудрых высотах» — о значении, ударении, пунктуации (по Мандельштаму)

Tags: пунктуация, значение-слов, словосочетания, поэзия

В смиренномудрых высотах
Зажглись осенние Плеяды.
И нету никакой отрады,
И нету горечи в мирах.

Во всем однообразный смысл
И совершенная свобода:
Не воплощает ли природа
Гармонию высоких числ?

Но выпал снег — и нагота
Деревьев траурною стала;
Напрасно вечером зияла
Небес златая пустота;

И белый, черный, золотой **—**
Печальнейшее из созвучий **—**
Отозвалося неминучей
И окончательной зимой.

О. Мандельштам. [В смиренномудрых высотах](https://www.litres.ru/book/osip-mandelshtam/za-to-chto-ya-ruki-tvoi-ne-sumel-uderzhat-31727662/chitat-onlayn/page-10/)

**1.** Слово "смиренномудрие" по смыслу относится только к людям.
А *смиренномудрые высоты* — какие они?
Куда ставится ударение в слове "высотах"?

**2.** Пунктуация в последних строках имеется и [другая](https://xn--80apgoet0f.xn--p1ai/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B8/13348/%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85):

И **—** белый, черный, золотой **—**
Печальнейшее из созвучий **—**
Отозвалося неминучей
И окончательной зимой.

Какая из них правильная — как думаете?

Answer (score 2):

> В смиренномудрых высотАх
> Зажглись осенние ПлеЯды.
> И нету никакой отрАды,
> И нету горечи в мирАх.

Плеяды зажглись где? В высотАх, от слова высотА, вроде как небо - небесах, а не небах. Осенние плеяды - мечты или стремления осени, то есть зрелого этапа человека, про возраст, поэтому и смиренномудрых высотах - тоже про человека и его года, в смиренномудрых летах. Нет ни отрады, но нет и горечи, есть только стремление к высоте.

белый, черный, золотой - возможно, имперский флаг. И белый... - наверное лучше, так как цвета не по порядку следования, поэтому И относится только к одному цвету, иначе пришлось бы упорядочивать.

Решил проверить догадку, нашёл ответ о другом [стихотворении с похожей палитрой](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/179633967).

> Обе строки указывают на имперский флаг, все три цвета которого (белый в декабрьском снеге, желтый - в яичном желтке и черный в дегте) упоминаются. ОЭМ вспоминает петербургское детство, когда Питер был столицей.

`Ленинград`
`Я вернулся в мой город, знакомый до слез,`
`До прожилок, до детских припухлых желез.`
`Ты вернулся сюда, так глотай же скорей`
`Рыбий жир ленинградских речных фонарей,`
`Узнавай же скорее декабрьский денек,`
`Где к зловещему дегтю подмешан желток.`
`Петербург! я еще не хочу умирать!`
`У тебя телефонов моих номера.`
`Петербург! У меня еще есть адреса,`
`По которым найду мертвецов голоса.`
`Я на лестнице черной живу, и в висок`
`Ударяет мне вырванный с мясом звонок,`
`И всю ночь напролет жду гостей дорогих,`
`Шевеля кандалами цепочек дверных.`

> Печальнейшее из созвучий —
> Отозвалося неминучей
> И окончательной зимой.\

Зима - Февральская революция, конец монархии.

насчёт 1909 года, вот примеры стихов этого периода:

> Есть целомудренные чары —
> Высокий лад, глубокий мир,
> Далеко от эфирных лир
> Мной установленные лары.
> ...Иных богов не надо славить:
> Они как равные с тобой,
> И, осторожною рукой,
> Позволено их переставить.

> ... Пускай мгновения стекает муть —
> Узора милого не зачеркнуть.

> Ни о чём не нужно говорить,
> Ничему не следует учить,
> И печальна так и хороша
> Темная звериная душа:
> Ничему не хочет научить,
> Не умеет вовсе говорить
> И плывет дельфином молодым
> По седым пучинам мировым.

> Спокойно дышат моря груди,
> Но, как безумный, светел день,
> И пены бледная сирень
> В черно-лазоревом сосуде.
> ...Останься пеной, Афродита

> Я счастлив жестокой обидою,
> И в жизни, похожей на сон,
> Я каждому тайно завидую
> И в каждого тайно влюблен

То есть всё предельно мило, живо, лирично, чувственно, по-юношески, иногда даже дерзко, но в целом, ни разу не сложно. Никакого надрыва в каждой строчке. А "Ленинград" - 1930 очень похож по настроению и по белый-чёрный-жёлтый. Так что я склонен считать, что стихотворение неверно датировано, либо дописано. И что еще харрактерно, у него в ранних стихотворениях везде Я, мне, моя, реже она, или его. А тут нет местоимений, самоотрешённость и сплошной символизм.

Comment: Мм... Стихотворение написано в 1909 году.

Comment: Да, есть такая дата, зачем 18-летнему Мандельштаму писать про смиренномудрую высоту, однообразный смысл во всём - он такой зануда всегда был что ли)? Может в качестве шифровки 1909? Я конечно люблю цифры, но склонен всё же не только на них ориентироваться. Цифры можно любые написать. Ну или как ещё это всё объяснить? А так выходит он пророк, мистика, ещё большая нелепица, чем сфальсифицированные цифры.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Хотя я могу и ошибаться, но пока у меня нет ни лучшей версии, ни какой другой, как это всё сшить.

Comment: в 1909 году он вот такие стихи писал: Да обретут мои уста

Первоначальную немоту,

Как кристаллическую ноту,

Что от рождения чиста!

Останься пеной, Афродита,

И, слово, в музыку вернись,

И, сердце, сердца устыдись,

С первоосновой жизни слито!

Comment: А не про траурную наготу. У него в 1908-1909 весьма жизнерадостные и игривые стишки, и весьма эмоциональные.

Comment: Спасибо за интерес к вопросу и ваше мнение!