Как объяснить выбор: тире или единый знак?
Вот стихотворение:
Когда меня отправят под арест
Без выкупа, залога и отсрочки,
Не глыба камня, не могильный крест —
Мне памятником будут эти строчки.

Ты вновь и вновь найдешь в моих стихах
Все, что во мне тебе принадлежало.
Пускай земле достанется мой прах, —
Ты, потеряв меня, утратишь мало.

С тобою будет лучшее во мне.
А смерть возьмет от жизни быстротечной
Осадок, остающийся на дне,
То, что похитить мог бродяга встречный,

Ей — черепки разбитого ковша,
Тебе — мое вино, моя душа.

Семантика  в обоих случаях одинаковая: обозначено противопоставление. Но как объяснить, что выбраны разные знаки (тире или запятая и тире)?

Ваш вариант действительно верный? Встречаются варианты стиха с поставленной запятой.

Ну вот, например:  http://eng-poetry.ru/PrintPoemE.php?PoemId=537   Так что смотреть – поставьте сами знаки и объясните выбор))  Считайте, что это стихотворение неизвестного поэта, а вам нужно проверить правильность письма)

Да, действительно, в подавляющем большинстве случаев пунктуация именно такая, как указана в вопросе:
Не глыба камня, не могильный крест — (1)
Мне памятником будут эти строчки.
Пускай земле достанется мой прах, — (2)
Ты, потеряв меня, утратишь мало.
(1) В некоторых изданиях имеется запятая с тире, в редких — двоеточие.
Если представить предложение без инверсии во второй части, то оно будет выглядеть так:
Не глыба камня, не могильный крест [а или а именно] эти строчки будут мне памятником.
После слова "крест" в этом случае необходима запятая. В отсутствие же союза пауза становится выраженной и тире, "съедающее" запятую, здесь вполне логично.
(2) В этом предложении, считаю, надо обязательно поставить запятую перед тире — чтобы пауза была длинной, чтобы читатель остановился и у него не возникло неправильного восприятия строк:
Пускай земле достанется мой прах — ты...

Спасибо за ваше мнение и интерес к теме, голос от меня. А правила можно какие-нибудь для единого знака? //  Меня в этом стихотворении (кроме необычных, просто потрясающих метафор)   привлекла нестандартная грамматика в первой части: СПП, пропуск союза А при наличии  противопоставления, инверсия однородных членов. Ну и тире как сильный знак в середине главного предложения по сравнению с окружающими запятыми. Разве это норма для СПП? Может, возможно другое оформление? Я об этом стала думать.

Честно говоря, мне правила не нужны: я единый знак ставлю по слуху грамматике.  И это просто из любопытства, ведь  обычно знаки нужно правилами объяснять.

Вы правы, Sharon, такие конструкции встречаются нечасто... Пунктуация в стихах — вещь особенная. Иногда ее трудно объять правилами (особенно тогда, когда гениальны оба — и автор, и переводчик). Да и надо ли?.. Я сделала попытку, возможно не очень удачную. Где ж мне сравниться?

А где же мне?)  Я ведь тоже не знаю, тоже думаю.  Хочется  увидеть нечто цельное в этом предложении, в этой грамматике. Я вам благодарна, не сердитесь на меня.  Я вообще благодарна тем, с кем могу говорить о нем.  Может, кто еще примет участие в обсуждении темы, давайте послушаем.

Давайте... Помню, Вам хотелось поговорить о Мандельштаме. У меня был вопрос о его стихотворении. (С ударением там все понятно. А вот другие темы остались.) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478358/%d0%9e-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%83

Спасибо,  я посмотрела тему, но пока не готова ответить. Надо подумать, вжиться в образ.  Мнение уже высказано интересное. Да и Лебедь с Эйвона  для меня сейчас особенно притягателен,  больше о нем читаю. Но Мандельштам  поэт  тоже любимый, но не так много я про него знаю, чтобы участвовать в диалоге с автором ответа на  равных. Но чуть позже попробую непременно, да)

Я обозначу свою версию постановки знаков в первой части стихотворения:
  Когда меня отправят под арест
  Без выкупа, залога и отсрочки,
  Не глыба камня, не могильный крест —
  Мне памятником будут эти строчки.


Это СПП с придаточным времени (союз КОГДА), но там интересная конструкция: противопоставление однородных членов в главной части не обозначено союзом А, при этом два из них инверсированы в начало главного предложения и обособлены тире.

Таким образом, тире как бы делит все предложение на две части, в то время главный знак должен находиться между главным и придаточным предложением. Поэтому я бы использовала единый знак после придаточного:
Когда меня отправят под арест
Без выкупа, залога и отсрочки, —
Не глыба камня, не могильный крест —
Мне памятником будут эти строчки.


Любопытна и сама конструкция главной части предложения: Не глыба камня, не могильный крест — Мне памятником будут эти строчки.

Оборот напоминает мне именительный темы, вынесенный в начало предложения и обособленный тире. При таком объяснении все выглядит красиво, как риторическая фигура. Можно пользоваться)

Новое решение никому не интересно, что и следовало ожидать.
